# ggplot2 boxplot medians aren't plotting as expected

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, median

So, I have a fairly large dataset [(Dropbox: csv file)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0wnivgfn0z0mjre/boxplot.csv?dl=0) that I'm trying to plot using `geom_boxplot`. The following produces what appears to be a reasonable plot:

```
require(reshape2)
require(ggplot2)
require(scales)
require(grid)
require(gridExtra)

df <- read.csv("\\Downloads\\boxplot.csv", na.strings = "*")
df$year <- factor(df$year, levels = c(2010,2011,2012,2013,2014), labels = c(2010,2011,2012,2013,2014))

d <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = year, y = value)) +
    geom_boxplot(aes(fill = station)) + 
    facet_grid(station~.) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 15)) + 
    theme(legend.position = "none"))
d
```

However, when you dig a little deeper, problems creep in that freak me out.  When I labeled the boxplot medians with their values, the following plot results.

```
df.m <- aggregate(value~year+station, data = df, FUN = function(x) median(x))
d <- d + geom_text(data = df.m, aes(x = year, y = value, label = value)) 
d
```

[image: boxplots-with-medians-labelled]

The medians plotted by geom_boxplot aren't at the medians at all. The labels are plotted at the correct y-axis value, but the middle hinge of the boxplots are definitely not at the medians. I've been stumped by this for a few days now.

What is the reason for this? How can this type of display be produced with correct medians? How can this plot be debugged or diagnosed?

Comment: Your example code has an inconsistency in it. You are calling `geom_text` against `temp.m` but the median was computed into `turb.m`. Could this be the issue?

Comment: Ah! Good call on that... I tried to remove my inconsistencies from the original code, but I missed that one.

That error would cause the geom_text layer to fail, but even without the geom_text added to the plot, the medians are still drawn incorrectly on the boxplots.

Comment: Is the "*" in the `value` field to be interpreted as NA?

Comment: And what data type is `year` in your data frame?

Comment: When I read in the data using read.csv, I set na.strings = "*".

Comment: (Edit timed out...)

I've tried df$year as numeric, factor, and int to no avail. It's strange, because some of the boxplots appear correctly, with the medians labelled as expected.

When I subset down to a year and station that isn't plotting correctly, I'm still getting a weird boxplot. I've scoured the data with a minimal dataset and I can't find any problem!

Comment: Can you post your code to read the posted dataset as well? I do not find the same problem of your post. The boxplots I see are heavily right skewed and the median text are right on the hinge because the whole box is quite flat.

Comment: I've edited the original post to include the full code to generate the faceted plot. As you can see [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5hdnttszxss29c7/plot.tif?dl=0), where the labels fail to fall on the boxplot horizontal line, there's a problem.

I've gone as far as to pare down the dataset to a single station (discharge), using only 2012 data and I still get the exact same boxplot.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The solution to this question is in the application of `scale_y_continuous`. ggplot2 will perform operations in the following order:

1. Scale Transformations
2. Statistical Computations
3. Coordinate Transformations

In this case, because a scale transformation is invoked, ggplot2 excludes data outside the scale limits for the statistical computation of the boxplot hinges. The medians calculated by the `aggregate` function and used in the `geom_text` instruction will use the entire dataset, however. This can result in different median hinges and text labels.

The solution is to omit the `scale_y_continuous` instruction and instead use:

```
d <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = year, y = value)) +
geom_boxplot(aes(fill = station)) + 
facet_grid(station~.) +
theme(legend.position = "none")) +
coord_cartesian(y = c(0,15))
```

This allows ggplot2 to calculate the boxplot hinge stats using the entire dataset, while limiting the plot size of the figure.

Comment: This is a major problem with ggplot2 imho. I've been using it for a long time without picking up on this - there ought to be warnings.

Comment: It had made me very cautious - and nervous - about how I interpret my data. I questioned everything about R when I first encountered this,until I finally understood what was going on.

I'm sure there are a number of casual R/ggplot users who aren't aware that this could be impacting their work.

Comment: @Ryan Pugh I would be grateful for examples of "statistical computations" within the ggplot code!